# How to determine if a PyObject is a numpy PyArrayObject

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-api

I'm new to the Python C-API.

Currently I get objects from the embedded Python module via

```
PyObject* a = (PyObject*) PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "a");
std::cout << "a as long is " << PyLong_AsLong(a) << std::endl;
```

I access numpy objects via

```
PyArrayObject* array = (PyArrayObject*) PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "A");
```

How can I test if the object is a really a `PyArrayObject`? In other words how to do what I would do in Python via `isinstance(a, numpy.ndarray)`?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`PyArray_Check`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/array.html#c.PyArray_Check) or [`PyArray_CheckExact`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/array.html#c.PyArray_CheckExact). Use `PyArray_Check` if subclasses are okay, or `PyArray_CheckExact` if you need an object with type exactly `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: This does not work for me ?! But I need to note, that I'm also not able to allocate a numpy array from C++ side (same code on macOS with clang and Linux with gcc 10).

```std::cout << "check a: " << PyArray_Check(a) << std::endl;
```

results in 
`isinstance : unknown location:0: fatal error: in embedded_python: memory access violation at address: 0x00000010: no mapping at fault address`

Comment: I made a mistake pasting my error: It is `check a: unknown location:0: fatal error: in   "embedded_python": memory access violation at   address: 0x00000010: no mapping at fault address`- both solutions fail for me?!

Comment: That sounds like a new question.  Instead of trying to figure that out here in the comments, create a new question about the error.